# $.getJson reuse method for rendering 2 different controls

Tags: jquery

Im doing a $.getJson call which I want to be able to reuse for different ui rendering.
I want to use the GetUserRoles(userName) method for rendering 2 ui controls with 2 different calls.  The first call is made to populate a dropdownlist.  Now I want to make another call to the method which will draw a UL list on the same page.  How do I do it using the same method.

```
 function GetUserRoles(userName) {
            var param = { userName: userName };
            $.getJSON(userRoleController, param, function (data) { GetUserRolesSuccess(data, userName); });
        }

        function GetUserRolesSuccess(data,userName) {
            $("#userdetails #roles").html("");
            if (data.length != 0) {
                var roles = "<table class='rolesTable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
                for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (data[i] != undefined) roles += "<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td><td><a href='#' onclick=\"RemoveUserFromRole('" + data[i] + "','" + userName + "');\">Remove</a></td></tr>";
                }
                roles += "</table>";
            }
            else {
                roles = "<p class='norolesavailable'>No roles assigned to user.</p>";
            }

            $("#userdetails #roles").html(roles); 
        }
```

Comment: why do you want to use the same function for two different types of calls?

Comment: Its the same call but Im using the out results to render 2 different html. e.g the first call to the methods returns a dropdownlist and the second one returns a list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to `GetUserRoles` and `GetUserRolesSuccess` which indicates the type of control to render, so the method signatures look like `GetUserRoles(userName, controlToRender)` and `GetUserRolesSuccess(data, userName, controlToRender)`. Modify `GetUserRoles` to look like:

```
 function GetUserRoles(userName, controlToRender) {
     var param = { userName: userName };
     $.getJSON(userRoleController, param, function (data) { GetUserRolesSuccess(data, userName, controlToRender); });
 }
```

and finally add a condition which renders a control based on the new parameter, e.g.:

```
function GetUserRolesSuccess(data, userName, controlToRender) {
    if(controlToRender == 'ul') {
        // make a ul
    } else if(controlToRender == 'whatever') {
        // make a whatever
    }
}
```

Now simply call `GetUserRoles` passing in your new argument, e.g.:

```
GetUserRoles('Jeff123', 'ul');
GetUserRoles('Jeff123', 'foo');
```